# Get the EOM and MOM of any month in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, date

I've periods of time every 15 days, MOM and EOM.

What I need to check is if a date value on a date field is prior to the current period minus 1.

For example, if today is 12/29, the period is 12/31, and i need to check

```
if prior < 12/15
```

How can i get the EOM (End Of Month, i mean, the last day of the month) and the MOM (Middle of month, it's like every 15th of month) with GETDATE() function without doing a DATEADD with -15 days (because in feb will be fail, and i don't care the month)

Any help or work around will be preciated.

Thanks

Comment: So MOM should be 14 for February?

Comment: not really, it's always 15, but i don't want hard code it.

Comment: for example: jan: 15 and 31, feb: 15 and 28 or 29, mar: 15 and 31, apr: 15 and 30, may: 15 and 31, etc.

Comment: Hmmm, this seems like a situation where hard coding the MOM might be the way to go.  Is there a specific reason that you don't want to hard code it?

Comment: thinking in hard coding, every 15 and the count number of month. By how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking in a work around, what I did it was this:

If actual day < 15 then get the month actual, convert to the first day of the month (01) and minus 1 day. I get the last day of the prior month. (EOM - 1 period)

If actual day > 15, then the prior period (MOM - 1 period) is: 15 of actual month.

It's a query with if structure.

**If someone has a better answer, please answer it and I'll be accept it.**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the value 15 then put it in your code.

If that is against your company's policies then challenge the person that made that policy. Writing 5 lines of code to replace two characters is not a good coding...

If writing the 5 lines made your application much more flexible then maybe I could understand, but you are still "hard coding" 15 into your comparisons.